# How to interrupt a PHP loop?

Tags: php, laravel-5, interrupt, jobs

I have a **Laravel 5.2** job that I generally want running non-stop. For illustration, let's say it generates some random number and then broadcasts it through an event to the front-end.

```
/**
 * Execute the job. Generate a random number.
 */
public function handle()
{
    $number = rand();
    event(new NumberWasGenerated($number)); 
}
```

For whatever reason, I want this job to run indefinitely. So, I made another job which loops and keeps dispatching new `GenerateNumber`jobs.

```
/**
 * Execute the job. Continuously generate numbers.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    while (true) {
        $this->dispatch(new GenerateNumber());
    }
}
```

I do however want to be able to "turn off" the generator should I decide to. This is where I am having trouble.

Ideally I would like to be able to hit a route like `/abort`which would then send an **interrupt** to my generator loop and halt its execution. How can I do this?

Alternatively, I could try a **polling** approach. I tried to use something like:

```
/**
 * Execute the job. Continuously generate numbers.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Config::set('shouldGenerate', true);

    while (Config::get('shouldGenerate')) {
        $this->dispatch(new GenerateNumber());
    }
}
```

Then, in my `controller` method for `/abort` I have

```
public function abort()
{
    Config::set('shouldGenerate', false);
}
```

However, the `abort` doesn't seem to be working. I think the problem seems to be that the `abort` method never gets a chance to execute because the generator loop is being a ball hog, but I am not sure why that would be the case.

### Question:

1) Can I achieve this using an **interrupt** approach?
2) If not, how can I achieve this through **polling**?

Comment: Your abort wouldn't work because you're setting `shouldGenerate` to `true` as the method runs. You should run a check before you set to make sure it's present. i.e. (`if( empty(Config::get('shouldGenerate')) ) { Config::set('shouldGenerate', true); }`)

Comment: I'd say you shoudl just use laravel's built in `taskscheduling` with a `truth test constraint` personally

Comment: You can try with the `interrupt` approach as per my understanding this will be better option rather than polling.

Comment: @AlankarMore can you please explain how I would do that?

Comment: Are you using linux machine?  which driver for queue? I mean redis or other ?

Comment: @AlankarMore My local environment is on a Mac, production will be Ubuntu. My driver queue is redis, but I'm open to switching that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by combination of both options

- Interrupt
- Polling

You can rewrite your abort action as follow

```
public function abort()
{
    Config::set('shouldGenerate', false);
    exec('PATH/TO/YOUR/RDIS/SERVER/src/redis-cli FLUSHDB');    
}
```

And change the handle method as follow:

```
/**
 * Execute the job. Continuously generate numbers.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $shouldGenerate = Config::get('shouldGenerate');
    while ($shouldGenerate) {
        $this->dispatch(new GenerateNumber());
    }
}
```

You can read more about the FLUSHDB of Redis server [HERE](http://redis.io/commands/flushdb) 
Delete all the keys of the currently selected DB. This command never fails

I hope this will work for you. Make sure your operating system user must have permission to execute the shell commands via script.

Comment: thanks, that did seem to work great for stopping the generating loop... the only problem is that now I can't restart it properly. I first set `Config::set('shouldGenerate', true);`but it seems that it is only running once and then quitting, and I can't get it to loop again.... ???

Comment: I think the issue is that I also just flushed away my `Config`s. it seems that `shouldGenerate` is now set to `null`. This is true even after I try to use `set`again, and even after i did a `migrate:refresh`

Comment: This you can mange by file system instead of saving the value in the config. Because as per my understanding if you have used the `php artisan cache:clear` it will clear your configuration. So simply read json from file which have the value of `shouldGenerate` and set it back again as per your need. As simple we are using `sessions` is PHP using `file` as driver

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try it out later when I get back to work. Thanks for your help.